# What is this strange number when I use pivot function in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

[image: This is the original DataFrame structure]

I want to aggregate `docvector` as it is, ordered by `unixReviewTime` grouped by `reviewerID` from the original pandas DataFrame above. The code I wrote is as below.

```
user_reviews = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["reviewerID","unixReviewTime"],values=["docvector"], aggfunc=lambda x: x)
```

As a result, I got this strange **user_reviews** DataFrame which has numbers ahead of each docvector. Here 80839, 130296, 128549, 86624 in the image below. These numbers are not present in the original.

[image]

What are these numbers, why they are created and how can I make a pivot table without these numbers?

Comment: This is what causes the problem: `aggfunc=lambda x: x` What aggregation function do you want to use? And what about unixereviewtime column? Do you want to group on this too?

Comment: @IoaTzimas I want to keep docvector as it is so I used this function.

Comment: Why not just use sorting? No need to use pivot without aggregation. Try `df.sort_values(by=["reviewerID","unixReviewTime"])`

Comment: @IoaTzimas Thanks. But I want to use ```reviewerID``` as index.

Answer (score 0):

When using lambda x:x as aggfunc, x means a pd.Series for each group, which in this cases causes the problem

One solution is to use x.iloc[0] in order to get the value of docvector column, considering that there are no duplicates in rest columns (which I assume is correct as you couldn't use lambda x:x as well)

Given this, the following should work properly:

```
user_reviews = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["reviewerID","unixReviewTime"],values=["docvector"], aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong.

The problem was in `aggfunc=lambda x: x` where returned x by lambda is Dataframe object that looks like below. It includes index, value and meta information.

[image]

So using `aggfunc=lambda x: x.values` or `aggfunc=lambda x: x.to_numpy` both worked for my case. `aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0]` only showed 'Function does not reduce' error message. Many thanks for your considerate comments!